# Unary Operator with a while loop in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, unary-operator

I'm trying to get a bash script setup so it'll move files up to a specified size limit(in this case 1GB) from one directory to another.  I'm trying to get it to enter the loop but I'm having issues with the while statement.  It keeps returning the below output and I'm not sure why.  If I try to use "$currentSize" in the while bash says it's expecting an integer comparison.  But variables in bash are supposed to be untyped, so I can't cast it to an intiger, right?  Any help is appropriated.

Output

```
54585096

1048576
./dbsFill.bsh: line 9: [: -lt: unary operator expected
```

Code

```
#!/bin/bash

currentSize= du -s /root/Dropbox | cut -f 1
maxFillSize=1048576
echo $currentSize
echo $maxFillSize

cd /srv/fs/toSort/sortBackup
while [ $currentSize -lt $maxFillSize ]

do
        #fileToMove= ls -1
        #rsync -barv --remove-source-files $fileToMove /root/Dropbox/sortme
#       mv -t /root/Dropbox/sortme $(ls -1 | head -n 1)
        #find . -type f -exec mv -t /root/Dropbox/sortme {} \;
        #currentSize= du -s /root/Dropbox | cut -f 1
#       sleep 5
        echo Were are here
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve by:

```
currentSize= du -s /root/Dropbox | cut -f 1
```

is to capture the current size of `/root/Dropbox` in `currentSize`.  That isn't happening.  That's because whitespace is significant when setting shell variables, so there's a difference between:

```
myVar=foo
```

and

```
myVar= foo
```

The latter tries to evaluate `foo` with the environment variable `myVar` set to nothing.

Bottom line: `currentSize` was getting set to nothing, and line 9 became:

```
while [ -lt 1048576 ]
```

and of course, `-lt` isn't a unary operator which is what the shell is expecting in that situation.

To achieve your intent, use [Bash command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution):

```
currentSize=$( du -s /root/Dropbox | cut -f 1 )
```

Comment: +1 same answer, but best explanation of what needed changing and why.

Comment: Ah, perfect thank you.  I didn't grasp that whitepsace mattered when setting variables, that makes excellent sense.  And explaining the reference to command subsitution solved the next issue this script had.  :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> currentSize= du -s /root/Dropbox | cut -f 1
> ```

This does not do what you think it does.

```
currentSize=$(du -s /root/Dropbox | cut -f 1)
```

Comment: `./dbsFill.bsh: line 3: 37188888: command not found


1048576
./dbsFill.bsh: line 9: [: -lt: unary operator expected` is the result of changing that command.  I agree that line is probably the problem, but I'm not sure what your changes do.

Answer (score 0):

you need to re-write your 'currentSize ...' line as

```
currentSize=$(du-s /root/Dropbox | cut -f 1)
```

Your code left the value of currentSize empty.

You can spot such problems (with a little practice), but using the shell debugging feature

```
set -vx
```

at the top of your script, or if you think you're pretty sure where there's a problem, surround your suspiocus code like:

```
set -vx
myProblematicCode
set +vx
```

(the `set +vx` turns off debug mode.)

I hope this helps.